# MVC 4 [ _Layout.cshtml ] - js files functionality breaking on bulk js files inclusion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on MVC 4 with _Layout.cshtml. I have bulk js files from many of views. I have removed all js files from the normal view files and included in _Layout.cshtml file like below...

> **Issue**: Functionality is breaking in many places (Eg: Kendo UI
>   dropdownlist) is disappearing immediately after visible for 1 second
>   or so...

Can somebody please guide me is there any problem with re-ordering or something else...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-jquery.easing.1.3.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-jquery.jscrollpane.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-jquery.mousewheel.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-jquery.flexslider.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-generic.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-kendo-all.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-temp-create.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-switch.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tabdrop.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-daterangepicker.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-moment.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-tel-input.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.nestable.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-form-generator.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/clients-init.js")"></script>
```

> **PS**: I have almsost 200 view files.. Where as in some views I need
>   first 8 .js files and another view, first 3 .js + last 2 .js
>   files etc...

Comment: You should consider using bundles to manage this better

Comment: Did you try seeing the browser console for any errors while loading the files?

Comment: Also as @StephenMuecke suggested, use bundles. But thats not the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I follow to investigate in similar problem

1- Make sure that all of this files are exist in your source code and all of their paths are correct.

2- If you are using chrome open the console by clicking f12 button or from the settings and see the errors there (usually you will see a missing file or 404 can not load) this might happen because of some conflicts between js files(could be solved by reordering the files or remove some of them).

3- Or you can try to remove some of the script files (comment them or so) and see what is the effect of this then try to add them one by one till you figure out what is the problem.